# Run software from iso format w/o extra software?

Tags: iso-image

I recently downloaded software in an `.iso` format.

Do I need to download any special software to run this file?

Comment: You might want to state your operating system--the answer is different depending on the OS.

Answer (score 10):

Short Answer: Yes.

Long Answer: An ISO is an optical media (CD, DVD, Blu-Ray, etc.) image.  Normally you would use some sort of burning software (ImgBurn, CDBurnerXP, Nero, Roxio, etc.) to burn this ISO to a disc, then use the disc to install from.

Alternatively, there is software available like Virtual Clone Drive, DVDFab Virtual Drive, or Daemon Tools (among others) that will let you create a virtual CD/DVD drive and mount the ISO to a drive letter.

Comment: +1 for Virtual Clone Drive, http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html

Answer (score 4):

Most decompression programs can also simply extract an ISO file to a folder. You can then run the setup executable directly from the extracted files.

Answer (score 1):

An iso (short for [ISO 9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660)) is a CD image. On most desktop [operating systems](http://apps.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=OperatingSystems) other than Windows, you can access its contents by mounting it through [FuseISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuseiso/) (e.g. Ubuntu: [fuseiso](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fuseiso) [image: Install fuseiso]).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows consider using [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/). There are plenty of reviews on [CNET](http://download.cnet.com/PowerISO/3000-2646_4-10439118.html) and I consider it one of the better shareware versions. It is not only capable of reading ISO formats but it can also mount them as virtual CD/DVD drives.